# SuperScrollorama: Reversing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, gsap

This is my first post, but I'm a long-time viewer. Hope someone can help - this one's been driving me crazy and I've tried and tried to find an answer but to no avail.

Basically, I'm updating a friend's website with a few stylistic scrolling elements. I chose SuperScrollorama as it looks completely amazing, although I'm ready to accept that it's complete overkill for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm really interested in SuperScrollorama anyway, so I suppose I partly chose it just so I could try to use it!

Anyway, the idea I'm trying to implement involves:

Single page website, where section one is simply a centred, large (650px width) image and a navigation menu `<ul>` centred and fixed to the top of the page containing 6 `<li>` elements.

On scrolling down, I want the image to shrink to 250px width, and I want to make a space of 250px between the third and fourth `<li>` for the shrunken image to scroll into and then remain for the duration of the scroll. I'm trying to create the space by adding a margin-right to the third `<li>`. (I appreciate this may give me undesirable side-effects, one being that it won't be completely centred. Suggestions welcome here too! The problem that I'm about to describe, however, I also experienced when trying other methods based around floating and using two separate divs so the margin-right itself doesn't seem to be the root cause)

Now, I've managed to get the image to shrink and attach itself to the top of the page without too much trouble.

The problem that I'm having is with the margin-right. On page load, the `<ul>` appears centred and uniformly spread, as I want it to. The margin-right value on the third `<li>` is 0. However, the value jumps from 0 to 89px following the tiniest of scroll events. Continuing the scroll works as desired, but on scrolling back up, the margin returns to 89px and then stops.

Here's the code that I've got:

HTML:

```
<body>
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#programme">PROGRAMME</a></li>
            <li id="grow_margin"><a href="#tickets">TICKETS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="#venue">VENUE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>   

</nav>

<header id="fix-it">

    <h1><img id="scale-it" src="/images/logo.png" />TITLE</h1>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
text-align: center;
}



nav ul {
list-style: none;
height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
color:#bbbbbb;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 8px;
}

header {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}

header h1 {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

And the JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var controller = $.superscrollorama({
        reverse: true
    });
        var windowHeight=window.innerHeight;
        var scrollDuration = windowHeight; 

        controller.addTween('#grow_margin', 
            TweenMax.to( $('#grow_margin'), .25, {css:{'margin-right':'250px'}, immediateRender:true}), scrollDuration);
        controller.addTween('#scale-it', 
            TweenMax.fromTo( $('#scale-it'), .25, {css:{width:'650px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{width:'250px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 
            scrollDuration);
        controller.addTween('#fix-it', 
            TweenMax.fromTo( $('#fix-it'), .25, {css:{top:'40%'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{top:'4'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 
            scrollDuration);    
    });

</script>
```

Any help would be so much appreciated! It's driving me absolutely crazy!

Thank you!

Rob

Comment: Here it is on jsfiddle: 

[http://jsfiddle.net/aTz4X/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/aTz4X/1/)

As you can see, it starts completely centred. Then, as soon as you start to scroll, the margin jumps to a random value. Scrolling down from there works as intended, but on scrolling back up the margin only returns to the random value that it initially jumped to. As in, not 0.

Comment: Right, have been playing around in JSFiddle all morning. If I remove the SuperScrollorama-ness of it, and just use a regular tween over 5 seconds, the margin increases gradually as it's supposed to.

It also doesn't seem to be a problem with the CSS. I've tried removing all margins, positions etc and the problem persists throughout.

I'm thinking it's something to do with the interaction between SuperScrollorama and TweenMax. I've been reading the documentation for both over and over again, and whilst I admit it may be going over my head, I can't see a reason why what I've got isn't working.